# Random number after run a docker for ASP on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-mvc-5, dockerfile

I'm trying to put my new ASP Website (MCV5) on the AWS server. For this I used EC2 and I created a virtual machine on linux. I also build my docker and now I'm trying to run it with:

```
sudo docker run -t -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

But each time I just get a random number like this :

> 940e7abfe315d32cc8f5cfeb0c1f13750377fe091aa43b5b7ba4

When I try to know if my docker is running with:

```
sudo docker ps
```

no information is showed...

For information, when I put `sudo docker images`, I get my application created.

My Dockerfile contain:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "kestrel"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-d` means to run detached. The number you see is the container id.

If you want to get information about the container, you can use that container id

```
docker inspect <container id>
docker logs <container id>
```

If you'd like the container to run and print logs to the terminal, remove the `-d`